# Limit of zero padding

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, zero-pad

I have a signal in energy. But it's not from zero to `E`, but from `A` to `B`. It has `N` data points. If I add `2.5N` zeros to the left of `A`, I will have a good enough signal in time after Fourier Transform. However, is it too much zeros to add? How much zeros can be added without producing too much artifacts in the signal?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Maybe you can find better help [**here**](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Zero-padding before an FFT or DFT just results in the interpolation of more points on the same spectral result curve.  You can zero-pad by a very large number if you just want a lot of smoothly interpolated points between the non-zero-padded FFT result.

Comment: Also see: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/741/why-should-i-zero-pad-a-signal-before-taking-the-fourier-transform